# Convert azure.timestamp to NiFi date data type in NiFi expression language

Tags: azure-blob-storage, apache-nifi

I am using the NiFi ListAzureBlobStorage to get the available blob objects. The processor creates a flowfile for each object with the attributes containing the object metadata. I want to filter on the azure.timestamp attribute, but I do not know what the numeric value represents and how it relates to the NiFi's expression language date data type. I want to compare it with a known date so I need to convert it to a NiFi data-time variable first. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add an example for such timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [code](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-azure-bundle/nifi-azure-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/azure/storage/utils/BlobInfo.java) it is already in "NiFi format" which means a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Since it represents the number of milliseconds passed since 1/1/1970, you can compare this and the other timestamp using regular number comparison operators.
example: `${azure.timestamp:ge(${now()})}` - this will return true if the `azure.timestamp` is later(or equal) than the current timestamp(now). 
If you'd like to compare it to another attribute you can do this:
`${azure.timestamp:ge(${attribute.name})}`.

If you'd like to convert a different date into a unix timestamp, you can use [toDate](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#todate) and then [toNumber](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#tonumber), or to do the other way around, just use [format](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#format).

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your explanation. This is really helpful.